# Why is my dataframe returning 0 on the index column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm creating a matrix of random weights for 3 assets through the following code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

assets = ['WMT', 'FB', 'BP']
num_assets = len(assets)

df1 = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(1000) :
    weights = np.random.random(num_assets)
    weights /= np.sum(weights)

    df1 = pd.concat( [df1, pd.DataFrame( [weights], columns= assets)] )
```

which provides me with the following output in which the first column is filled with zero's as index as per below

[image]

I expected a sequential range(1000) on the first column. What am I missing here?

Comment: add reset_index: ```df1 = pd.concat( [df1, pd.DataFrame( [weights], columns= assets)]).reset_index()```

Comment: @DeanTaler there's no `reset_index` parameter in `pandas.concat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `ignore_index=True` in `pd.concat` hence your last line of code should update to

```py
    df1 = pd.concat( [df1, pd.DataFrame( [weights], columns= assets)],ignore_index=True)
```